# Xcode 10 GM does not show storyboard graphic elements

Tags: xcode, xcode10

I started using the beta version from its beginnings (I had installed xcode 9 and xcode 10 beta), today I uninstalled xcode9 and installed xcode10GM but when there was a project in my storyboard the graphic elements were not shown.

Additionally it shows also the message "Failed to render and update auto layout status"

Up to now, do the following:

1. Delete the folder my project in `DerivedData`
2. Clear project: <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>
3. build your project <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.

All this with unsuccessful results.

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

[image: IB]

[image: xcode 10 GM]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved restarting the PC and everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Editor> Refresh All Views.